# How does one represent a self-join in jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jooq

I have the following schema (SQLite) for capturing messages from messengers:

```
create table if not exists spot_message
(
    id             unsigned big int primary key not null,
    messenger_id   text not null,
    messenger_name text not null,
    message_type   text not null,
    timestamp      text not null,
    latitude       real not null,
    longitude      real not null
);
```

I use the following self-join in order to find the latest message from every sender:

```
select t1.*
from spot_message t1
         join (select messenger_id, max(timestamp) timestamp
               from spot_message
               group by messenger_id) t2 on t1.messenger_id = t2.messenger_id and t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp;
```

It is not clear to me how to represent this in jOOQ.

I currently have:

```
DSL.using(c.get())
    .select(asterisk())
    .from(table("spot_message").as("t1"))
    .join(select(field("messenger_id"), max(field("timestamp"))).from(table("spot_message"))
        .groupBy(field("messenger_id")))
        .on(field("messenger_id")
                .eq(field("messenger_id"))
                .and(field("timestamp")
                        .eq(field("timestamp"))));
```

But it is not clear how I express the "as" for the table name of the joined table ("t2").

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using?

Comment: @LukasEder I am using SQLite. I just updated the question. Thanks for asking. I should have specified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answering your question

To alias a `Select` as a derived table, you can either use:

- [`Select.asTable(alias)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/TableLike.html#asTable(java.lang.String))
- [`DSL.table(select).as(alias)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table(org.jooq.Select))

You're using the [plain SQL API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) for query building, so you can just use any SQL expression in your strings, such as e.g. `"t2.messenger_id"`. This should work:

```java
DSL.using(c.get())
    .select(asterisk())
    .from(table("spot_message").as("t1"))
    .join(select(field("messenger_id"), max(field("timestamp")))
        .from(table("spot_message"))
        .groupBy(field("messenger_id")).asTable("t2")) // t2 alias here
    .on(field("t1.messenger_id") // Qualifications here, and below
        .eq(field("t2.messenger_id"))
    .and(field("t1.timestamp")
        .eq(field("t2.timestamp"))));
```

However, this would be a bit more readable if you were [using code generation, which I recommend for various reasons](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/)

```java
SpotMessage t1 = SPOT_MESSAGE.as("t1");
SpotMessage t2 = SPOT_MESSAGE.as("t2");

DSL.using(c.get())
   .select(t1.asterisk())
   .from(t1)
   .join(
       select(t2.MESSENGER_ID, max(t2.TIMESTAMP).as(t2.TIMESTAMP))
       .from(t2)
       .groupBy(t2.MESSENGER_ID).asTable(t2))
   .on(t1.MESSENGER_ID.eq(t2.MESSENGER_ID))
   .and(t1.TIMESTAMP.eq(t2.TIMESTAMP));
```

#### Alternative using window functions

Since you're using SQLite, which supports [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html), why not just use those? You can even use the [`QUALIFY` syntax](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/qualify-clause/), which jOOQ can emulate for you if you're using the commercial distributions:

#### In SQL:

```sql
select *
from spot_message
qualify timestamp = max(timestamp) over (partition by messenger_id)
```

#### In jOOQ:

```java
ctx.selectFrom(SPOT_MESSAGE)
   .qualify(SPOT_MESSAGE.TIMESTAMP.eq(
       max(SPOT_MESSAGE.TIMESTAMP).over(partitionBy(SPOT_MESSAGE.MESSENGER_ID))
   ));
```

If `QUALIFY` isn't available to you, you can still emulate it manually by wrapping the query in a derived table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    spot_message.*, 
    timestamp = max(timestamp) over (partition by messenger_id) AS is_max
  FROM spot_message
) AS t
WHERE is_max
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It was very helpful. I had to make a small change to alias max(field("timestamp")) as "timestamp". Surprisingly, the wrapped query derived table option you suggested did not perform as well.